# missing required parameters for route ajax post

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have used resource controller with the following route:

```
 Route::resource('invoice','InvoiceController');
```

Here is the ajax request but the problem is defining route in ajax and that's why geting following Error:

```
missing required parameters for route
```

Ajax request:

```
  <a href="" class="btn btn-danger m-btn m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only" data-id="{{$row->id}}"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i> </a>

 function() {

      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
              }
      });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{route('invoice.destroy')}}",
            data: {id:id},
            success: function (data) {
                          //
                }         
        });
});
```

Comment: route is a function within laravel. As JS code is not executed the way you provided it I have to suspect that you are not providing proper context to anlyse the problem. please provide the complete view file